# My notification is sent without satisfying if condition that I set in code

Tags: java, android

I am working in Android Studio to develop my app but my notification is sent without condition satisfying.

Notification is always sent when new temperature value is read by app.

```
if(TEMP_float[i] >= 37){
                            appended_Values = appended_Values + UID[i] + TEMP_float[i] + "\n";
                            myUserList.setText(appended_Values);
                            if(TEMP_float[i] >= 37){
                                long [] vibe = {0,500};
                                Uri notificationsound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(hightemprecord.this, "MyNotification")
                                        .setContentTitle("Notification")
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp)
                                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                                        .setSound(notificationsound)
                                        .setVibrate(vibe)
                                        .setContentText("Alert! High Temperature is detected!!!");
                                NotificationManagerCompat manager =NotificationManagerCompat.from(hightemprecord.this);
                                manager.notify(999, builder.build());}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is proabably an issue of when you call that function and what values TEMP_float contains, try logging instead of notification to see when your conditions are met like so

```
Log.d("conditions met", "value=" + TEMP_float[i]);
```